# Django retrieve all related attributes for model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am writing a store based app. Say theres Store A , Store A can have multiple users, and each user can belong to multiple stores. However, each store has Products and each Product has sizes associated with them.

```
class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey("Product")
    size = models.CharField(choices=SIZES, max_length=5)
    pid = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100, verbose_name="Product ID")
    id_type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=ID_TYPES, default="UPC")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    store = models.ForeignKey("Store")

    class Meta:
        unique_together  = ("store", "pid")

class Product(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Parent SKU", help_text="reference# - Color Code")
    # Google docs sp key
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    store_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    objects = StoreManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

so i had to write a custom manager for Product in order to filter all products by store, and override the queryset method for this model's admin class, and do so for EVERY attribute belonging to said store. So basically my question is, is there a way to filter all attributes related to a store per store, ex products, tickets, variations

*EDIT*
This is the product manager so far

```
class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def active(self, **kwargs):
        return self.filter(in_queue=False, **kwargs)

    def by_store(self, store=None, **kwargs):
        return self.filter(store__id__exact=store, **kwargs)

    def from_user(self, request):
        qs = self.model.objects.none()
        for store in request.user.store_set.all():
            qs = qs | store.product_set.filter(in_queue=False)
        return qs
```

so basically, in order to display the products in the change list page, i use the from user method, which returns all the products available to the logged in user

Comment: Can you provide the code for the custom manager so far? That would help.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like what you want to be using is the the [django "Sites" framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/)

add a ForeignKey to Store to point to Site and make it unique.

it may be wise to point Variation and Products' ForeignKeys at Site instead of Store at this point too so that in your views you can filter your results by current site.

Comment: this is a good solution, however i don't have multiple domains, all stores are in the same db which is running in one domain

Comment: so then store.pk should be in either the session or a cookie, something so that you know what the users active store is. I would suggest forgoing the managers and simply filter on the fk

Comment: this would work, except that one user can have multiple stores, altho this solution is one i had not considered, thanks :D